# Weird comparison behavior in mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

What am I missing? 
I am comparing 3 objects:

`userID` was pulled in a model search before

`req.user._id` is the session variable holding the user id

and `docs[i].toWho` points to the same id.

When I compare them I get a false negative. Why?

At first I thought the comparison fails because `docs[i].toWho` is a mongoose objectID and the others are strings, so I cast them as mongoose objectIDs.

Still, results fail. See output:

```
57a8d7f189d00bfc1917187e 57a8d7f189d00bfc1917187e 57a8d7f189d00bfc1917187e
false false true
false false true
```

code:

```
console.log(docs[i].toWho,req.user._id,userID)
console.log(docs[i].toWho==req.user._id,docs[i].toWho==userID,req.user._id==userID)
console.log(docs[i].toWho==mongoose.Types.ObjectId(req.user._id),docs[i].toWho==mongoose.Types.ObjectId(userID),mongoose.Types.ObjectId(req.user._id)==mongoose.Types.ObjectId(userID))
```

**Edit:**

This entire thing originated when I tried to debug an update query.

```
Notification.update({
                        toWho: req.user_id
                    }, {
                        $set: { seen: true }
                    }, {
                        multi: true
                    }, function (err,count) {});
```

And no record was updated. All the records are still showing `seen=false`

**Edit 2**

Turns out, I had a typo in my code. I user req.user_id instead of req.user._id

Thank you Thomas

Comment: You should cast the `ObjectID` to string, not the other way round. Objects are only equal when they point to the same reference.

Comment: It worked! but... sadly it doesn't help my cause. Please see my edit.

Comment: Mongoose (as mongo) accept ObjectId or string in query.
`multi : true`is useless if you put a unique id in the query (let it empty `{}` ).
If you want update all your record let the query empty `{}`.

Comment: Try `toWho: new ObjectId(req.user_id)`

Comment: @ThomasLeduc to who can repeat many times in my collection. It's a reference, not a real ID.

Comment: @str look at the [mongo native driver for nodejs](https://github.com/christkv/node-mongodb-native#data-types).
String and ObjectId are accepted !

Comment: @str it didn't work

Comment: @ThomasLeduc so why is this happening? I'm querying this db for 2 years, everything always works fine, this is the first time such a thing happened to me!

Comment: Ok and if you count the result of the query ? how many match have you ?
`Notification.find({toWho:req.user_id})`

Comment: @ThomasLeduc I get 0 { ok: 1, nModified: 0, n: 0 }

I even tried to change the query from update to find, but it returns nothing.

Comment: Just wondering is it `req.user._id` or `req.user_id`, coz you have both in your question

Comment: @ThomasLeduc WOW! this looks promising! Let me check!

Comment: That did it! Thank @ThomasLeduc. When things act this weird it's usually a simpler reason!

Comment: @ThomasLeduc The link you provided says the opposite: "but you must convert the string back into an ObjectID before you can use it in the database". As `toWho` is an `ObjectId`, so must be `req.user._id`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not a real answer because it was a mistake.

String are not allowed in querying and we have to cast it in mongoDB (thx to @str).

The mistake was a typing mistake (`req.user_id` => `req.user._id`)

But to compare ObjectId, it's easier to convert them into string and compare them with `==`.

Comment: It still deserves it !

Comment: You linked to a massively outdated fork of the original project. The real documentation can be found here: http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/

Comment: Ok ok, Thx @str ;)